# HTTP.GET implements a interface error

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework, get

i'm working on a small app to learn better IONIC.
But i got a huge problem, when i call the http.get.
Here's the response of the request in json.

```
    {
"coord":{"lon":-73.57,"lat":45.5},
"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02d"}],
"base":"stations","main":{"temp":22.91,"pressure":1010,"humidity":60,"temp_min":22,"temp_max":24},
"visibility":48279,
"wind":{"speed":7.7,"deg":270,"gust":11.3},
"clouds":{"all":20},
"dt":1526320800,
sys":"type":1,"id":3829,"message":0.0902,"country":"CA",
"sunrise":1526289839,"sunset":1526343480},
id":6077243,
"name":"Montreal","cod":200}
```

**And this is my code, i would like to get like Coord.lat & Coord.lon to show it on the screen, also the weather etc..**

```
loadPosition(){

        this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
         // resp.coords.latitude
         //let userPosition: LatLng = news LatLng(resp.coords.latitude,resp.coords.longitude);
         //console.log(resp.coords.latitude + ' ' + resp.coords.longitude);\
          this.lng = resp.coords.longitude;
            this.lat = resp.coords.latitude;
            this.test = this.Pro.getWeatherPerLatLng(this.lat,this.lng).subscribe((data: Weather) => this.weather.coord.lon = {lon:data['lon']
        });
            console.log(this.test, 'Sortie de la fonction');
            console.log('Weather Object', this.weather);
        });


    }
```

**With this small interface :**

```
    export interface Weather{
  coord: {
    lon: number,
    lat: number
  },
  weather: [
    {
      id: number,
      main: String,
      description: String,
      icon: String
    }
  ],
  base: String,
  main: {
    temp: number,
    pressure: number,
    humidity: number,
    temp_min: number,
    temp_max: number
  },
  visibility: number,
  wind: {
    speed: number,
    deg: number
  },
  clouds: {
    all: number
  },
  dt: number,
  sys: {
    type: number,
    id: number,
    message: number,
    country: String,
    sunrise: number,
    sunset: number
  },
  id: number,
  name: String,
  cod: number
}
```

Is there any solution to 'auto-implements' the interface i made or i have to do multiple *.subscribe((data: Weather) => this.weather.coord.lon = {lon:data['lon']* (which didn't work..) ?

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: You should put the `console.log` inside the `subscribe`, subscribe does (usually) asynchronous stuff, so by putting the `console.log` after the subscribe it gets executed while the code inside the `subscribe` has not been run.

Comment: Yes but the last code line **this.weather.coord.lon = {lon: data['lon']** don't work